# NSTextView - How to detect when it is clicked?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextfield

I'm trying to do this:

```
- (IBAction)textFieldSelected:(id)sender
{
    printf("clicou no text\n");
}
```

I "connect" this to my NSTextField through the Interface Builder.

When I first start the app, the **this NSTextField is already focused**. Then I click on a second NSTextField, and my first one lose the focus and I get the print statement. Clicking back and forth between theses NSTextField I see that the print statement is just called when I click on the NSTextField that it is not attached to it. I believe that it **just happens when the first one loses the focus.**

Q1: How do I do to have this print statement when the use click on the NSTextField (when it gets the focus)?

Q2: How do I avoid it to get the focus automatically when the app starts?

Comment: Take a look at the delegate methods of NSTextFieldDelegate resp. NSControlTextEditingDelegate.

Comment: control:textShouldBeginEditing:
"Invoked when the user tries to enter a character in a cell of a control that allows editing of text (such as a text field or form field)." This is not my case :/

Comment: You can overwrite (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder and post a notification in there. Be sure to return YES.

Comment: Are you saying that in every click on this view this method is gonna be called?
I thought that this method supposed to be called just in the initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the custom class of NSTextfield and then implement below method, so that whenever focus goes to the textfield below method will get called:-

```
   -(Bool)becomeFirstResponder{
     return YES}
```

Comment: Doing this, I'm not able anymore to drag a connection linking my class that inherits from NSTextField to the NSTextField element in the .xib file. :/

Comment: Go to the identity inspector of your text field in the xib. There change its class to your custom class.

Comment: I love you buddy. By the way, when my app starts, the NSTextView get focus automatically, does anybody know how to avoid it so that I can get focus just when the user clicks on it?

Comment: Try  return [super becomeFirstaresponder] inspite of returning YES and check??

Comment: I just did it: 
Click in the .xib, go into the Interface Builder > select your NSTextView > Show the Attributes Inspector > Control > State:
Check refuses First Responder